# How to enable the lan4 on zte F670L for internet usage?

Tags: router, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to connect via LAN cable to lan4 of the converge default router. Its model is F670L. I've tried changing the ethernet cable of LAN1 to LAN4 and it is working. Also tried using from LAN2 to LAN3 and it working so I found out that the culprit is LAN4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching, I found out that by default, the ZTE F670L routers LAN4 are locked and it is dedicated to IPTV. The good thing is you can enable it by going to the settings.

Just go to the Network, then click on port binding, uncheck the LAN4 and hit save.

Note: By checking the manual, the default password for superadmin access are the following
username: admin
password: Converge@zte123

You might wanna check your if the default password is like that.

[image]

Comment: Converve@zte123 or Converge@zte123 ?

Comment: Converge@zte123 - it has no space, C is capital.